# How do you get rid of the extra space that bold or large face characters make?

Tags: indentation

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\textbf{ \Large Blahblahblah}
\end{document}
```

For some reason `\textbf` or `\Large` creates this extra unwanted space from the left margine. How do I get rid of it? `\hfill` does nothing to shove the text back into place, `\begin{flushleft}...` lied and doesn't actually flush `\textbf` left.

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! Try `\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\textbf{\Large Blahblahblah}
\end{document}`.

Comment: That doesn't magically make it off topic, this is obviously related to TeX. There is a general rule in stackexchange to wait a day before accepting something as an official answer. Furthermore, if someone else has this question they can find the answer here instead of asking it again.

Comment: @VaneVoe Yes, off course it is on-topic. However, it is a tradition here that if a question is solved in comments, it will be closed as off-topic. Look at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/475926/156344) for example.

Comment: So you're saying people should blindly follow unofficial tradition just for tradition's sake instead of using basic, common-sense reasoning? That doesn't seem to speak to the rest of the community.

Comment: @JouleV Ironically I was mentioning this just a few moments on meta: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8116/121799. I agree with the OP that the question is not off-topic. So I add a community wiki answer. Please feel free to edit it.

Comment: Bold and large looks as if you trying to make a sectioning title - if yes don't hard format it like this but use a proper sectioning command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue has nothing to do with boldface versus normal. Rather, you see the default indent of paragraphs. One way to switch it off (for one paragraph) is to use `\noindent`.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{article}

\begin{document}

A normal paragraph.

\textbf{\Large A normal bold paragraph.}

\noindent
A normal paragraph with \texttt{\textbackslash noindent}.

\noindent\textbf{\Large A bold paragraph with \texttt{\textbackslash noindent}.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are two separate issues that keep the text from starting at the left-hand margin of the text block. Neither issue is actually associated with the fact that the text string happens to be rendered in bold&large.

Let's begin by studying an augmented version of the OP's MWE, along with a screenshot of the associated output. (The vertical line down the left-hand edge represents the edge of the text block.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe} % to show edges of text block
\newcommand\Once{Once upon a time, \dots} % test text string
\begin{document}
\vspace*{1mm}  % just for this example

\textbf{ \Large \Once} % OP's example

\textbf{\Large \Once} % no space before "\Large"

\Once % normal font size and font weight

\noindent
\textbf{\Large \Once} % no more indentation!

\setlength\parindent{0pt} % suppress paragraph indentation globally
\textbf{\Large \Once}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As the third line shows, the indentation issue is *not* caused by the fact that the text string is rendered in bold/large. Instead, it happens because (a) the text string occurs at the start of a (logical) paragraph and (b) the `article` document class (along with many other document classes) sets a non-zero value of `\parindent`, which is the parameter that governs how much the first line of a paragraph is indented.

Notice also that the first line is indented *even more* than the second line is. What is the difference between `\textbf{ \Large \Once}` and `\textbf{\Large \Once}`?  It's the whitespace character between `{` and `\Large`. TeX does not gobble up *all* whitespace character. Beware the Ides of March. And beware carelessly inserted whitespace.

The fourth and fifth lines show how to suppress the indentation of the first line of a paragraph: For one-off suppression, use `\noindent`; for global suppression, set `\parindent` to `0pt`. Aside: If you set `\parindent` to `0pt`, you should probably also set `\parskip` -- the parameter that governs the amount of vertical whitespace between paragraphs to a non-zero value, e.g., `\setlength\parskip{0.5\baselineskip}`.